# How to set node-cron to run in 12 hours

Tags: node.js, cron, node-cron

I wish to schedule a task in my node.JS project to run in 12 hours from the time of schedule. I tried using `0 */12 * * *` but it can only run at the 12th hour. How to do please?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [Bull.js](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull). I never used it for scheduling task (only one task after xx minutes). But according to their documentation, you can schedule/repeat a task.

Example code:

```js
paymentsQueue.process(function(job){
    // Check payments
});

 // Repeat payment job once every day at 3:15 (am)
 paymentsQueue.add(paymentsData, {repeat: {cron: '15 3 * * *'}});
```

[Link to doc](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull#repeated-jobs)

Quite easy to use as it follows [cron expression descriptor](https://bradymholt.github.io/cron-expression-descriptor/)